# Application level encryption and key renewal

Tags: encryption

I have a question related to encrypting data in the database, at the application level.

The application will encrypt the data (e.g. using AES) when persisting it to the database and decrypt the data once they have been retrieved from the database.

Is there any good technic to renew the encryption key.

If for example a company has a policy to renew the encryption key every two years we would end up in a position where we have to decrypt the overall database with the old key, and reencrypt it with the new one every two years.

Is there any technic to avoid such an issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming, but rather a feasibility question. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to decrypt the old data and reencrypt the new data.  Make sure you keep "key identifiers" to identify which key the data is encrypted with.

For more information, read about cryptoperiods [in the NIST key management document](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-57/sp800-57p1r4_draft.pdf).  You can also search for "re-encrypt" in the document.

Comment: I have to disagree. There ways to symmetrically re-encrypt ciphertexts without disclosing the plaintext in the process. An example is given [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/wang-sieve.pdf) (chapter 3.6 - "Re-encrypting data")

Comment: @ArtjomB.yes, homomorphic encryption can do that, but it is extremely slow and unpractical.  Gentry' homomorphic encryption is based upon lattices, but the poster here is talking about symmetric encryption like AES (a block cipher).  In this case, I stand by my answer.

Comment: There are many flavors of homomorphic encryption. I'm not talking about FHE by Gentry or Yao, which is not at all necessary here. Partially homomorphic schemes are fully sufficient, but you're right, they are not even close to being as fast as AES.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes Pailier scheme is practical, but the poster does mention AES in his post.  I think we are agreeing that both your points and my points are correct.  For a skilled cryptographer, maybe Pailier is a solution, for anybody else, got to do it the decrypt re-encrypt way!

Comment: Thanks a lot. for this. As proposed I will move it to cryptography

Comment: PS: I moved it to crypto: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35299/application-level-encryption-and-key-renewal. But I would be interesting in getting to know to what extend the technics you mentionned are industry ready?